# Which is the best way of loading jrxml file into java code

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Please tell me which is the best way of loading jrxml file into java code.
Some example:

First way:

```
InputStream input = ReportServlet.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
```

Second way:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
```

or directly:

```
jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(filename);
```

which is the best way,and if you have another way then suggest me.

Regards

Comment: if the xlm file is located within your application bundle, #1 may be the only way since File API only work with files residing directly in a file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If #1 works, it is the best way... using the classloader ensures your report design can be loaded even when you don't have filesystem access (like a network-backed loader).

I recommend after getting the `InputStream` that you start a `try` block and `close()` it in a `finally`.

Secondly, I recommend compiling the .jrxml file during your build process, and loading the .jasper file at runtime.